# unable to create node with FQDN for chef client configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I have created node through command **Knife node create node1** in my laptop(which is configured as chef-client) i am able to create the node , but it has no FQDN entry in it,so its affecting knife operations like executing recipes  to continue ,I tried to edit ,but no luck . Can anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

After you create a node, chef-client should run on this node at least once successfully, for automatic attributes (such as fqdn) to reach chef-server.

Comment: i ran the chef-client on this node , but still unable to see FQDN entry .